# Old code runs every time I run the program

Tags: netbeans, new-operator

I just installed netbeans 12.0 again (I formatted my computer previously), I was customizing it but now every time I make a code I have to click on the Clean And Build Project button before clicking on the Run button, which is quite a lot. tired and takes time, when that should be automatic.

For example: I create a `System.out.println ("Hello");` , I run the program and nothing appears on the console, I click the Clean And Build button and now it appear on the console; I change the message from "Hello" to "How are you?", I run the program and the "Hello" that I had written previously appears, that is, the application continues executing the previous code until I click Clean And Build. How can i solve this? Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps.**
**Note:Make sure your project haven't any errors.**

1. Go to the  project Explorer.
2. Right click  on your project.
3. Select Clean (Now your code  will clean).
4. After the clean  build  your project.
5. Then you can run your project.It  should be ok